# Extract List<> from List<>

Tags: .net, list

I have this problem:

```
List<string> a = {"aa","aaa","aaaa"}
List<string> b = {"bb","bbb","bbbb"}
```

I made `a.AddRange(b)` and after I need to extract List b from List a, to have it just like the begin, with the same elements. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Yes i know the number of elements, i try to concat List A and List B, and after some operations i want to have those 2 List just like in the start(same number of elements and same elements). But, the answer of RainbowFish is usefull.. THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always iterate over list b, and remove each item from list a:

```
b.ForEach(item => a.Remove(item));
```

Comment: Don't forget that if there were any elements in `a` that are identical to elements in `b`, this will cause you problems.

Comment: Yes, i will take care about this, but, for the moment i don't have this situation..